# How to define the optimal size of the buffer for a channel?

Tags: go, channel, goroutine

I know that the size of the buffer can play an important role in an application performance, however what is the best way to define a buffer size? What should I think about when sizing?

Something like “best practices”

Comment: At least give some use-case.

Comment: This depends on the use case. Many uses of channels are with unbuffered channels.

Comment: Best practices are: 0 for unbuffered channel for synchronisation). 1: when you want to decouple send and receive i.e. drop the sync from 1. N>1: if you have strong arguments that N is the right value for _that_ particular use case. Note that if the buffer capacity of a channel "play[s] an important role in [... your] application performance" then you have a problem with your design.

Comment: also, you size the buffer in order to prevent readers from starving, wait for some data to come.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To demonstrate that buffer size is actually an important factor in performance, you must measure the performance and try different sizes to compare. At that point, you already have a method to find a good value (simply keep testing and comparing).

As far as what to think about when sizing a channel, that may be a different question. The first thing to consider is the correctness of the program: meaning, will the program operate as intended and without faults. As mentioned in the comments, in a vast majority of cases the "correct" value is either 0 or 1, in synchronized and un-synchronized communication respectively.

If your channel does *require* a buffer size of more than 1, then you must determine the upper bound, or "worst case" number of values that the channel must hold at once to avoid deadlocks. If you can't determine what that number is **exactly**, that's a good sign that there is no upper bound. For example, if you have a recursive routine that sends messages, there may be no upper bound. If that is the case, you must redesign your program to store the values in a dynamic, way such as a slice.